# "SDL/SDL_opengl.h: No such file or directory" Can't seem to figure out why?

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, codeblocks, sdl-2

I am new to SDL and OpenGL and I'm trying to set up Codeblocks to start teaching myself these topics. I recently followed this tutorial: http://www.grhmedia.com/SDLOGLSetup.php to set up Codeblocks so I can start working with both. However, for some reason, whenever I try building my project in Codeblocks, I keep getting this error:

> SDL/SDL_opengl.h: No such file or directory.

Here is the sample program I am running to test everything.

```
#include <iostream>
#define NO_SDL_GLEXT
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_opengl.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
       std::cout << "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
       return -1;
    }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3); 
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3); 
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Example for SO", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if(window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Window could not be created! SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    auto ctx = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    auto init_res = glewInit();
    if(init_res != GLEW_OK)
    {
       std::cout << glewGetErrorString(glewInit()) << std::endl;
    } 
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The settings in my search directories are:

Here are my compiler settings:

```
C:\SDL\SDL-2.0.6\i686-w64-mingw32\include
C:\SDL\SDL_image-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include
C:\SDL\SDL_mixer-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include
C:\SDL\SDL_ttf-2.0.14\i686-w64-mingw32\include
C:\SDL\SDL_net-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include
```

Here are my Linker settings:

```
C:\SDL\SDL-2.0.6\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

C:\SDL\SDL_image-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

C:\SDL\SDL_mixer-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

C:\SDL\SDL_ttf-2.0.14\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

C:\SDL\SDL_net-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
```

And under my Linker Settings, under other linker options:
I have:

```
-lmingw32  -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
-lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_net
-lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglew32 -lglew32mx
```

Perhaps I am missing something? I have went over this tutorial numerous times and I always end up with the same error.

If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong or give me some insight into what is going on here that would cause this error and any remedies, that would be wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a `SDL_opengl.h` file in one of the directories? Are you sure that it shouldn't be `SDL2/SDL_opengl.h`?

Comment: HI BDL, that was the issue - thank you! I just had to change it from SDL_opengl.h to SDL2/SDL_opengl.h.